# Console log raw data of a failed Axios get request

Tags: javascript, error-handling, get, axios

I would like to make an Axios get request to a private server running Flask.
In case there is an internal error in the back-end it returns an response object and an error code.:

```
response_object = {
    "Success": False,
    'error': err.message
}
return response_object, 400
```

The served response_object should be accessible the front-end (React.js).

```
axios
  .get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/data`, {
    data: null,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.toJSON());
  });
```

I would expect the error to include the response object. If the URL is accessed manually in the browser the error data is visible. If there is no error in the back-end the get requests works properly. 
After googling for some time I found some issues that might relate to the mentioned problem. (That is why empty data is passed in the a get request).
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86
Please note that I am self taught so I might miss something obvious here. Thank you all and all the best.

Comment: if it's a 400 status code that it's throwing (you can confirm by using the Network tab in your browser), it will fall into the `catch` block, the only concern is the `toJSON()` call ... just do a simple `console.log(error.message)` to check if you ever get there... I leave you [a simple example](https://jsbin.com/kuzufuh/2/edit?html,js,output) so you see the catch in action

Comment: Worked, thank you ;) 
I though the toJSON() is necessary to parse the incoming data?
Still need some more grip for WebDev.

Comment: you can easily parse JSON using [`JSON.parse('{"a":1}')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and the reverse with [`JSON.stringify({ a:1 })`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll copy/paste my comment here so other can easily see the answer for the question

---

if it's a **400 status code** that it's throwing (you can confirm by using the Network tab in your browser), **it will fall into the catch block**, the only concern is the `toJSON()` call... just do a simple `console.log(error.message)` to check if you ever get there...

I leave you [a simple example](https://jsbin.com/kuzufuh/2/edit?html,js,output) so you see the catch in action

more information:

- in Axios, the response text is in `response.data`
- if you are receiving a JSON, the `response.data` will be automatically parsed
- you do not need to pass `data: null` as that's the default behavior, and it's not used in a `GET` call (you won't pass a body in a GET call)